# what ftdi windows driver for arduino nano

Tags: arduino-nano, ftdi

at http://www.ftdichip.com/FTDrivers.htm they seem to divide chips into two categories,  FT4222H vs. D2XX driver.

What's the correct for a arduino nano?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Official Arduino Nano](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardNano) has an FTDI FT232RL.

You want to use the [Virtual Com Port(VCP) Driver](http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/VCP.htm) so the FTDI device appears as a COM port under windows.

See the [getting started guide](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Windows#toc4) for details.

Comment: The nano board purchased was obviously not an official. Peter at http://www.amazon.co.uk/SODIAL-ATmega328-P-20AU-Module-Board-Blue-Black/dp/B00QPUEFNW/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1430991247&sr=8-1&keywords=arduino+nano
helps out with driver to the ftdi-chip clone:

http://www.wch.cn/downloads.php?name=pro&proid=65

All working.